# Chrome Extension - Capture data

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We are new to chrome extensions - what we are trying to do is create an extension that can capture information from the current browser window. As an example, if we went to http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables we would want to be able to pick out the teams name and details to be saved to our database for later use on our site.

Using jquery we initially added a button to the top of the page and when clicked, it would fire our jquery script and this worked fine but we would prefer to have an icon in the toolbar so when clicked we could navigate to the page and gather the info rather than adding a button to the page.

## Manifest is set up like so:

```
   {
   "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "registration",
    "version": "1",
    "permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js","app.js"]
    }]
    }
```

## content_script

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getHTML")
  sendResponse({data: document.getElementById('header').innerHTML});
else
  sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Any pointers would really be appreciated.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: See [`chrome.browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) or [`chrome.pageAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html).

Comment: Thanks Rob,

PageAction was what I was looking for.